# Is there a way to filter AWS Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing

I have a AWS load balancer with HTTPS pointing to an instance with HTTP. Problem is that I need part of my page supporting HTTP (without encryption) and part of my page with encryption. I would normally use Apache's redirect to point HTTP to HTTPS for the URLs I want, but this wouldn't work here because my instance is using HTTP only. 
How can I filter traffic so that I can accept HTTP in the balancer only for some URLs?

Edit:

I added the following to my Apache VirtualHost configuration based on Mark's answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still do this with Apache, just check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header instead of the protocol.

Here is the ELB header documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html

Comment: Looking around, found the Apache configuration to complete the job (added to the question). Thanks Mark!